# Upgraded botbuilder doesn't work when deployed to azure

Tags: javascript, azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

I have a bot built using botbuilder-js **v4.9.0** that works both in the local emulator and when deployed on Azure.
When I upgraded it to the latest **v4.11.0** version the bot works in the emulator locally but not when deployed to Azure. I'm using memory storage as it suits my needs. Also I'm behind a company firewall and hence cannot debug using ngrok.

What could be the issue? It's very strange and the exception messages don't help much.

Below is the exception from AppInsights:

POST to the bot's endpoint failed with HTTP status 500

```
Microsoft.Bot.Schema.BotException:
   at Microsoft.Bot.ChannelConnector.BotAPI+<PostActivityToBotAsync>d__35.MoveNext (Microsoft.Bot.Base.ChannelConnector, Version=3.2.3.13, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullMicrosoft.Bot.Base.ChannelConnector, Version=3.2.3.13, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\a\1\s\ChannelSDK\Microsoft.Bot.Base.ChannelConnector\API\BotAPI.csMicrosoft.Bot.Base.ChannelConnector, Version=3.2.3.13, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 483)
Inner exception System.Exception handled at Microsoft.Bot.ChannelConnector.BotAPI+<PostActivityToBotAsync>d__35.MoveNext:
   at Microsoft.Bot.ChannelConnector.BotAPI.ThrowOnFailedStatusCode (Microsoft.Bot.Base.ChannelConnector, Version=3.2.3.13, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullMicrosoft.Bot.Base.ChannelConnector, Version=3.2.3.13, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\a\1\s\ChannelSDK\Microsoft.Bot.Base.ChannelConnector\API\BotAPI.csMicrosoft.Bot.Base.ChannelConnector, Version=3.2.3.13, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 640)
   at Microsoft.Bot.ChannelConnector.BotAPI+<PostActivityToBotAsync>d__35.MoveNext (Microsoft.Bot.Base.ChannelConnector, Version=3.2.3.13, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullMicrosoft.Bot.Base.ChannelConnector, Version=3.2.3.13, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\a\1\s\ChannelSDK\Microsoft.Bot.Base.ChannelConnector\API\BotAPI.csMicrosoft.Bot.Base.ChannelConnector, Version=3.2.3.13, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 465)
```

Comment: A few starting questions: Have you verified the messaging endpoint hasn't changed? Have you verified the AppId / AppPassword are correct in the app service configuration and / or match the creds used locally? Can you verify the project is getting fully deployed and no lingering files are present that might be corrupting the instance? Are you able to update your post to include any of your `index.js`, `mainBot.js`, or `mainDialog.js` code? And, are you using the updated version of Emulator?

Comment: Also, if you are using memory storage in production, it is _highly_ recommended that you **DO NOT** as it is volatile and can return unexpected results.

Comment: Thanks @StevenKanberg, I did not change any settings and had verified them.  I've managed to fix the issue though. I had configured GitHub Actions to deploy the bot and it was working fine for v4.9.0. When I updated it to v4.11.0 the code deployed successfully but I was getting the above error when testing it.To fix it I had to zip and upload the code using **az-cli** and then it started working fine. I don't know why that worked but I tested it in two environments and that fixed the issue. Is az-cli doing something in the background with the runtime/settings?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. I suppose it could depend some on the command you are using. This [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/deployment/source?view=azure-cli-latest#az_webapp_deployment_source_config_zip) suggests you can use zip deployment, but I haven't heard of it being a requirement (not that it isn't).

Comment: Yes. I deployed using the command mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=javascript#deploy-code-to-azure) and it started working. Thanks.